# Crear un loop para un contador de palabras sobre una lista

Tags: python, pandas

La idea es que tengo una lista que va sacando tuits en cada refresh, así que va creando una lista de datos nuevos con sus fechas, tengo un contador de palabras y en suma el resultado esperado es que cuente las palabras y las asigne a una lista de fechas que se van actualizando, esta es mi lista de fechas...

```
    FechasListC = []
    for i in FechasList:
         if i not in FechasListC:
                FechasListC.append(i)
    print FechasListC
    [u'Jul07', u'Jul08', u'Jul10', u'Jul11', u'Jul12', u'Jul13', u'Jul14', 
    u'Jul19', u'Jul23', u'Jul25']
```

y mi contador es este...

```
    cv = CountVectorizer()
    count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(Jul07.text)

    jul07count = pd.DataFrame(cv.get_feature_names(), columns=["word"])
    jul07count["count"] = count_matrix.sum(axis=0).tolist()[0]
    jul07count = jul07count.sort_values("count", 
    ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    jul07count.set_index("word", inplace=True)

    cv = CountVectorizer()
    count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(Jul08.text)

    jul08count = pd.DataFrame(cv.get_feature_names(), columns=["word"])
    jul08count["count"] = count_matrix.sum(axis=0).tolist()[0]
    jul08count = jul08count.sort_values("count", 
    ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    jul08count.set_index("word", inplace=True)
```

La idea es que vaya creando solito esos "jul08count" en los contadores...

Mil gracias!!

Comment: Hola marixxza, la verdad es que me cuesta entender cual es tu pregunta, cuando dices creando solo esos "jul08count", que significa? quieres evitar crear el código para cada uno y quisieras hacerlo directamente desde los elementos de `FechasListC`? Si pudieras ampliar un poco la pregunta posiblemente tengas más suerte. Saludos

Comment: No entiendo, cual es tu pregunta. Podrias especificar lo de " Crear un loop para un contador de palabras sobre una lista".